# wordpress loop with two statement

Tags: php, wordpress

I try to make wordpress loop which display two last posts from selected category.
I know there's so many examples but I don't find anything working for me.

My code:

```
    <?php $query = new WP_Query( array( 'cat'=>'2', 'post_count'=>'2', )); ?>
     <?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>

     <div class="post">
     <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
     <div class="entry-date"><span><?php the_time('d-m-Y'); ?></span></div>
      <div class="entry">
        <?php the_content(); ?>
      </div>
     </div> 
     <?php endwhile; 
     wp_reset_postdata();
     else : ?>
     <p><?php _e( 'Empty.' ); ?></p>
     <?php endif; ?>
```

is working only when I remove

this `'post_count'=>'2'`

important instruction.

What am I doing wrong?
I will be grateful for your help

Comment: Try changing to `new WP_Query( array( 'cat'=>'2', 'posts_per_page'=>'2', )); ?>` . If that works then use `order` and `orderby` to bring the last ones..

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<?php
    global $post;
    $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 2, 'category' => 2 );

    $myposts = get_posts( $args );
    foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>

    <div class="post">
        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
        <div class="entry-date"><span><?php the_time('d-m-Y'); ?></span></div>
        <div class="entry">
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div>
    </div> 

<?php endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

Ref - https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts